# Retrieving max date from multiple columns, for dates before today

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've written some code to extract the latest date from multiple columns.

```
select (select max(LatestDate)
        from (values (col1),(col2),(col3)) as updatedate(LatestDate)
        ) as LatestDate

from table1
```

However, I only want to take the date if it's before today. When I run the code for the sample dates below, it gives me the latest date as 10/04/2019 which is after today.

The date that i'd want it to extract is 14/03/2019 (col2) as it's before today, and is the latest date of all the columns whose date is before today.

```
Today = 27/03/2019
col1 = 02/02/2019
col2 = 14/03/2019
col3 = 10/04/2019
```

Can anyone advise on this? Hope it makes sense.

Many thanks

afk

Comment: Hint:  Add a `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1):

You can use `APPLY` with `WHERE` clause :

```
select t.*, tt.LatestDate
from table1 t outer apply
     ( select max(LatestDate) as LatestDate
       from ( values (col1),(col2),(col3) ) as updatedate(LatestDate)
       where LatestDate < convert(date, GETDATE())
     ) tt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this - you can take the MAX date that is less than or equal to today:

```
with cte as 
(
  select * 
  from (values (col1),(col2),(col3)) as updatedate
)
select (
         select max(updatedate)
         from cte
         where updatedate <= GETDATE()
        ) as LatestDate
from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for achieving the same.

```
select (select max(LatestDate)
        from (values (col1),(col2),(col3)) as updatedate(LatestDate)
        where updatedate < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
        ) as LatestDate

from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `where` clause.  I would phrase the query using `cross apply`:

```
select max(LatestDate)
from table1 t1 cross apply
     (values (t1.col1), (t1.col2), (t1.col3)
     ) updatedate(LatestDate)
where updateddate.LatestDate < getdate();
```

Comment: Sure? `FROM .... FROM`? You will get _Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'_ Also from where T1 comes?

Comment: @Sami . . . The typo is fixed.

Comment: No, still the `t1` alias. and then you will also get _The multi-part identifier "updateddate.LatestDate" could not be bound._